# Redirect from http to https

Tags: .htaccess

For redirect from *http* and *http/www*  to  *https* - I use code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

but it call `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell this to `redirect` and `stop` once it does. Use the appropriate flags at the end when creating rewriterules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Clear your browser cache or try in another browser.

Comment: i install firefox fro that - problem is same)))

Comment: Can you give me example URL? You don't need to give real domain. Also are you using www or not? And do you want www?

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: same ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS